# How to use std::bind with lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std, stdbind

I am trying to use std::bind within my lambda:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    void func(std::string input)
    {
        std::cout << input << '\n';
    }

    void bind()
    {
        std::cout << "bind attempt" << '\n';
        auto f_sayHello = [this](std::string input) {std::bind(&Foo::func, this, input);};
        f_sayHello("say hello");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bind();    
}
```

What I do expect when I run this code, is to see following output

```
bind attempt
say hello
```

But I do only see "bind attempt".  I am pretty sure there is something I don't understand with lambda.

Comment: `std::bind(&Foo::func, this, input)();` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Wow, quick working answer.  Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> std::bind(&Foo::func, this, input);
> ```

This calls `std::bind`, which creates a functor that calls `this->func(input);`. However, `std::bind` doesn't call `this->func(input);` itself.

You could use

```
auto f = std::bind(&Foo::func, this, input);
f();
```

or

```
std::bind(&Foo::func, this, input)();
```

but in this case why not just write it the simple way?

```
this->func(input);
```

Comment: I need to pass an std::function to a 3rdParty, that is why.  So, I was playing around this new concept for me, trying to understand.  Thx for the answer.